# Does the nw:betweenness-centrality measure in Netlogo work on directed networks?

Tags: network-programming, netlogo

Does the nw:betweenness-centrality measure in the network extension in Netlogo consider directed networks? If I am interested in the betweenness of a node on a directed network does the calculation follow the direction of the links to calculate betweenness or does it treat the network as undirected?